# Grouped UITableView cell with right-aligned subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Consider a `UITableView` with grouped style. How can I add a subview to a cell and align it with the right (or left) border of the table view group, **without hardcoding the margin**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the subview to the cell's `contentView`. The `contentView` is adjusted for the margins and other accessories added to the cell.

Note that this will only work if you don't have any `accessoryType` or `accessoryView` set.